# ADAL.js SPA-request with Authorization token

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I am trying to make an application that is based on AzureAD. I have a functioning back-end, I also have one functional client service that can connect to the application by passing the access token in the header.

However, when I try to use ADAL.js to authorize through this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/folder',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getAuthHeaders(), },
        xhr: function () {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressBar, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: completeHandler = function (data) {
            alert('Success!');
            modal.remove();
            updateFileBrowsers(folderName);
        },
        error: errorHandler = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Fail! :(');
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }, 'json');
```

I only get a 401 in response from the server. The controller is very simple and it have on the API-access points the [Authorize] notation for the entire controller.

I have checked so that the token is not empty, which it isn't. I have added the App to the Azure applications. The exact same way of doing it generates a successful connection when using a controller that is used by a client background application who sign in and then set the header:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

The only difference I can see is that one uses ADAL.js and one use .NET native class to set the request header.

Clarification: The httpClient works like a charm. The SPA-solution refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 401 error, it seems that the token you were using is not able to authenticate for your service.

One possible reason is that you were using the incorrect token for the resource. 
You can parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/) to check whether the **aud** claim in the token is matched with the **audience** you config for the web API.

Another reason for this error is when you were using an expired token.

I suggest that you use the token which worked for the client background application to see whether the issue was fixed.